# Make many similar ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have three UIButtons and three UI UIlabels (above the button) on the MainStoryBoard. The UIButton is connected with each audio files by IBOutlet.

I would like to make many more similar views of this. (Just small changes of the audio files, text labels and button sizes and numbers).

I found that there are multiple ways to implement this. One is to instantiate a new view controller programmatically, the other is to create the View Controller and elements programmatically.

What would be the advantages and disadvantages of each measure?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    let url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music1.mp3")
    let url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music2.mp3")
    let url3 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music3.mp3")


    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton1: customButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton2: customButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton3: customButton!

        func player(url: URL) {
        do {
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
            player.play()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

   @IBAction func pushButton1(sender: UIButton) {
       player(url: url1)
    }

    @IBAction func pushButton2(sender: UIButton) {
       player(url: url2)
    }

    @IBAction func pushButton3(sender: UIButton) {
        player(url: url3)
        player.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use a single viewcontroller with a method that will let you appropriately fill some fields with the needed values? Make your urls as var fields in the class. Something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music1.mp3")
    var url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music2.mp3")
    var url3 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music3.mp3")


    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton1: customButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton2: customButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton3: customButton!

    func refill(song1: String, song2: String, song3: String) {
      url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(song1)
      url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(song2)
      url3 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(song3)

    }
    ...
}
```

You may also change the text label accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "appropriately fill some fields with the needed values"? I do not understand the concept :/

Comment: `var url1...` then `refill()` method. With let you defined constants.

Comment: Your spec is about having the same kind of view filled with different data, so a single view reloaded as needed is the right solution. If not, add some appropriate init method, instanciate your controller and view and push them.